# Installing superslides plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I need help with installing [this plug-in](http://nicinabox.com/superslides/#1). The download included a lot of files so I was a bit confused about which ones to use. The ones I have used have made no effect at all. I don't know whether it's the files or I haven't linked the files correctly (I do have all of the files in the same folder so that's not the problem).

I've used superslides.css, query.superslides.js and query.superslides.min.js.

This is the html used:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.superslides.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.superslides.min.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="superslides.css">

<body>
  <div id="slides">
  <div class="slides-container">
    <img src="http://flickholdr.com/1000/800" alt="">
    <img src="http://flickholdr.com/1000/800" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Can anybody with superslides experience help me? Thanks

Comment: You should look at the index.html file in branch gh-pages. https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides/blob/gh-pages/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you embed jQuery library ?

try this :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.superslides.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="superslides.css">

<body>
  <div id="slides">
  <div class="slides-container">
    <img src="http://flickholdr.com/1000/800" alt="">
    <img src="http://flickholdr.com/1000/800" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

You don't need to embed jQuery.superslides.min.js and jQuery.superslides.js, jQuery.superslides.min.js is just a minimified version of jQuery.superslides.js

Comment: OP: tweaking? What exactly? It could be useful for other readers of this question tomorrow or in a distant future...